# Can I specify different data directory for each database running on a single MySQL installation?

Tags: mysql

My question is:

Can I specify different data directory for each database running on a single MySQL installation? I have multiple large databases, I want to point each to it's own directory, each on a different mount (unique disk).

Image is worth a thousand words, so let me illustrate:

[image]

Trying something like this for some reason creates DB and Table, but ignores data directory and index directory options:

```
CREATE DATABASE `DB1` /*!40100 COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' */;
USE DB1;
CREATE TABLE `onDisk1` (
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/windows/share_data/mysql'
INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/windows/share_data/mysql'
;
```

Comment: Googling `mysql different data directory database` yields this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/how-to-set-a-specific-directory-location-for-individual-mysql-database

Answer (score -1):

Mysql support this, You can follow steps here 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-data-directories.html

Comment: That URL doesn't answer anything I was asking about. I need each DB to sit on different drive.